# Finding lines not starting the same, and editing those. (sed/vim)

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I would like to find lines that start with a number from 1 to 5 that do not start with the same pattern as any other line. Then, I would like to put an * in the beginning of those lines. Is there a way to do this in vim, sed, or maybe any other options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some example input and output, please.

Comment: if I had for example two lines starting with 189 and one line starting with 2358 it should change the line starting with 2358 to starting with *2358

Comment: Because like I said there are two lines starting with 189,

Comment: In general case mark the unique lines [or unique first group of digits] which are starting first number with number 1~5? Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The following command in vim does what has been asked:

```
:8,$s/^\([1-5].*\t\)\(.*\n[^\1].*\)/\*\1\2/g
```

Comment: hmm... I don't think it does... maybe in your case it did, but what if there is no tab? what if I don't want to start on line 8? what about the last line of the file? Where is the explanation to make this useful to others?